# Recursive function return null value

Tags: php, recursion

[image]

I have Used recursive function to get the category full path like **Access Control/CARDS/FOBS** from above table structure but my recursive function return null value.

`function xyz($id,$parent) {`

```
if($parent == '0') {
   //my code working fine
   //return 
} 
else 
{
    $catid = $id; //here 25 coming

    $cat_array        =  array();
    $category_array   =  $this->Recursive($catid,$cat_array);   
    //echo $category_array;exit; getting Null result
    return $category_array ;

    }
```

}

function Recursive($catid,$cat_array)
  {

```
  $sql       = mysql_query("Select bg_category_id,parent_id,title from categories_list 
               Where bg_category_id = '".$catid."'");
  $result    = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

  array_push($cat_array,$result['title']); 

  if($result['parent_id'] != '0') {

     $this->Recursive($result['parent_id'],$cat_array) ;

  } else {  

    if(count($cat_array) > 0){
       $k =  implode("/",$cat_array);
     }
     //echo $k;exit; getting desired result FOBS/CARDS/Access Control 
    return $k;

  }
```

}

Comment: you don't return anything in `if($result['parent_id'] != '0') {` so you have null

Comment: In `Recursive`, shouldn't `$category_array` be `$cat_array`?

Comment: Sorry.Yes It is $cat_array. I am unable to edit my post now.

Comment: I have modified my code. But till now I getting null value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to return the recursive function when you recurse, otherwise it will return nothing.

```
if($result['parent_id'] != '0') {

   return $this->Recursive($result['parent_id'],$category_array) ;

 }
```

Comment: I have modified my post. Sorry for previous post. But till now I am getting null value.

Comment: @user3051318 You still don't have a `return` statement on this line.

Comment: @dave thanks a lot.Your code works fine. Can you please explain why it needs return because my Recursive function already return one value.